# How to use fcitx in wslg on win11?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, input-method, fcitx

`WSLg` on `Windows 11` can run `Linux` GUI.

The writing method in `Linux` GUI (e.g. `gedit`) is different from the Windows input methods

I installed `fcitx`, but there are several problems:

1. the icon doesn't show on the `Windows` toolbar panel, so cannot toggle different input methods by clicking icons
2. some keyboards don't work. `Wubi` and `Polish` keyboards works, but `Hebrew`, `Greek`, and `Russian` are still using `Polish` alphabets
3. how to autostart `fcitx`? When starting `Linux` GUI, I should manually start `fcitx`, this is boring. So I try to install a `Linux` desktop `LxQt`, but the desktop cannot fill the whole screen (I will ask in [seperated post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/686691/266769) for this).

So would you please help me to solve these problems?

Comment: This is rather unclear; you've tagged LXQt, but an example of application you use is GTK (`gedit`) and not Qt5. Your post is mixing different things; why not use `featherpad` or a Qt5 editor...   You don't mention an on-topic OS, this isn't a Linxu support site; refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic     `LXQt Session Settings` has a autostart feature which will cause programs to start at login.

Comment: Tried the more modern fcitx5? As regards autostarting at login, please make use of `im-config`.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Thank you for this information, I first tried fcitx5 on Lubuntu, it works very well. Then I tried on wsl2, always has the error "Cannot connect to Fcitx by Dbus, is Fcitx running?" And I could find someone who shared their experience with fcitx5 on WSLg

Comment: @JohnPaulQiangChen: I know nothing about WSL. Maybe you want to bring up the issue at https://discourse.ubuntu.com

Answer (score 1):

**1) install `fcitx5` with bash commands below:**

```
# https://forum.ubuntu.org.cn/viewtopic.php?t=491625
# 安装fcitx5
sudo apt remove --purge ibus*

sudo apt update
sudo apt install fcitx5 \
fcitx5-frontend-gtk2 \
fcitx5-frontend-gtk3 \
fcitx5-chinese-addons  #contain wubi
# fcitx5自启动
sudo tee /etc/X11/Xsession.d/73fcitx5_start > /dev/null << 'EOF'
#!/bin/sh

if [ -x /usr/bin/fcitx5 ] && [ -x /usr/bin/im-config ]; then
    if [ ! -f $HOME/.xinputrc ]; then
        /usr/bin/im-config -n fcitx5 && export XMODIFIERS=@im=fcitx || true
    fi

    if [ "$XMODIFIERS" = "@im=fcitx" ]; then
        if [ -f /usr/lib/*/gtk-2.0/*/immodules/im-fcitx5.so ] && [ -f /usr/lib/*/gtk-3.0/*/immodules/im-fcitx5.so ]; then
            export GTK_IM_MODULE=fcitx
        fi
        if [ -f /usr/lib/*/qt4/plugins/inputmethods/qtim-fcitx5.so ]; then
            export QT4_IM_MODULE=fcitx
        fi
        if [ -f /usr/lib/*/qt5/plugins/platforminputcontexts/libfcitx5platforminputcontextplugin.so ]; then
            export QT_IM_MODULE=fcitx
            fi
        fi
    if [ -x /usr/bin/fcitx5-remote ]; then
        /usr/bin/fcitx5-remote > /dev/null || /usr/bin/fcitx5
    fi
    if [ -x /usr/bin/im-launch ]; then
        STARTUP="/usr/bin/im-launch $STARTUP"
    fi
fi
EOF
# 删除用户ibus输入法列表
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[]"
# 选择fcitx5输入法
im-config -n fcitx5
# 生成配置文件
mkdir -p ~/.config/fcitx5
cat > ~/.config/fcitx5/profile << 'EOF'
[Groups/0]
# Group Name
Name=Default
# Layout
Default Layout=us
# Default Input Method
DefaultIM=pinyin

[Groups/0/Items/0]
# Name
Name=keyboard-us
# Layout
Layout=

[Groups/0/Items/1]
# Name
Name=pinyin
# Layout
Layout=

[GroupOrder]
0=Default
EOF
# 安装并启用gnome-shell-extension-kimpanel扩展
wget https://extensions.gnome.org/extension-data/kimpanelkde.org.v55.shell-extension.zip
gnome-extensions install kimpanelkde.org.v55.shell-extension.zip
gnome-extensions enable kimpanel@kde.org
```

---

**2) SOURCE FCITX5 WHEN LAUNCING TERMINAL**

At the moment I have only half solved this problem.

According to [this post](https://yanqiyu.info/2021/06/29/wslg-gpu/), the problem is with `wayland`, so need to add some lines to `.profile` or `.bashrc`

```
# https://yanqiyu.info/2021/06/29/wslg-gpu/
daemonize -e /tmp/fcitx5.log -o /tmp/fcitx5.log -p /tmp/fcitx5.pid -l /tmp/fcitx5.pid -a /usr/bin/fcitx5 --disable=wayland
export INPUT_METHOD=fcitx
export GTK_IM_MODULE=fcitx
export QT_IM_MODULE=fcitx
export XMODIFIERS=@im=fcitx
```

But my `WSL2` use `top` shows that `fcitx5` is running on starting the system, however, I just couldn't activate it!!

I will be gratitude if someone could tell me what's wrong there.

So now I couldn't put these lines in `.profile` or `.bashrc`. I put in a file called `source_fcitx5.sh`, and need manually activate `fcitx5`

```
source source_fcitx5.sh
```

Comment: It looks like you posted under a new/different account from your original question.  Any reason why?  It's no problem to post (and even accept) a self-answer.  You can always accept a different answer if something better comes along.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Thank you for pointing it out, I appreciate it, God bless!